# Difficulty in finding correct xpath

Tags: xpath

[image]

I try to select a button but because there are multiple classes with the naem 'btn btn-primary btn-block. I need to use a operator for the xpath.

What I tried is:

```
//div[@class='row rowOverflowVisible'] and a[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']
//div[@class='row rowOverflowVisible' and @class='btn btn-primary].
```

But both of them gives me 0 results back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `and` operator as below

```
//div[@class='row rowOverflowVisible' and .//a[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']]
```

to locate `div`... or

```
//div[@class='row rowOverflowVisible']//a[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']
```

to locate link

Comment: Thanks. The second one helps me the most.